# mysqldump test locking tables

Tags: mysql, database, locking

We have production mysql DB around `35G` (innoDB) and we have notice when `mysqldump` start application get unstable. we use following command to run dump

`mysqldump --password=XXXX --add-drop-table foo | gzip -c > foo.dmp.gz`

after googling people said `mysqldump` lock table before dumping data so people suggested using `--single-transaction` flag for `innoDB`

so for experiment i started mysqldump manually and run some query on tables read/write and it allowed me to perform all operation while mysqldump was running so how do i reproduce this behavior that mysqldump really locking my table which causing application accessibility?

- Does mysqldump lock Read Operation or Just Write on table?
- We have few DB using `MyISAM` in that case what we should do to avoid locks

Comment: Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `--single-transaction` to avoid table locks on InnoDB tables.

There's nothing you can really do about MyISAM, though you really shouldn't be using MyISAM. The best workaround is to create a read replica and make backups from the replica so that the locks don't impact the application.

What you should find is that while a backup is running, a `READ LOCAL` lock is held on the tables in the single database that is currently being backed up, meaning that you can read from the tables but writes (insert/update/delete) will block *except for* certain inserts on MyISAM that can be achieved without disturbing the lock.  Those may be allowed.  The easiest way to see this happening is to repeatedly query `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` to find threads that are blocking.

Comment: You are right, i tested and it blocked my write operation, Is it advisable to convert `MyISAM` to `InnoDB` ? what i should be careful about converting table