# mysqldump vs select *

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to export some tables from a db and I'm wondering what's the difference between:

- select * => get the result and export in CSV (from workbench)

Or

- mysqldump in csv directly?

Is mysqldump also using a select * underneath? I afraid to block the DB with my select * since the table is pretty large.
Would I risk to block the db by using mysqldump?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.eversql.com/how-to-backup-mysql-database-using-mysqldump-without-locking/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382596/mysqldump-test-locking-tables

Comment: Are your tables MYISAM or INNODB

Comment: ... or SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dumping InnoDB tables, then `mysqldump --single-transaction` does not lock tables. It uses a transaction to ensure a consistent data dump.

If you're not using InnoDB tables, why aren't you?